# Has anyone got .NET 7.0 to work with Visual Studio 2022 Professional

Tags: .net

Just as the subject says, I'm trying to see if I can upgrade an existing project to .NET 7.0 and I can't get it to show up in the targeted frameworks dropdown. The highest displayed is .NET 6.0.  I've tried starting a new project, both before and after restarting my machine. Below is my `dotnet --info` dump

````
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   7.0.100-preview.1.22110.4
 Commit:    129d2465c8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.1.22110.4\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 7.0.0-preview.1.22076.8
  Commit:  405337939c

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.100-preview.1.22110.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0-preview.1.22109.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0-preview.1.22076.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0-preview.1.22077.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]```
````

Comment: (Modern) preview versions of .NET are only (officially) supported by preview versions of VS, so get the latest 2022 preview. You *should* be able to build 7.0 apps in non-preview versions as well as long as you tweak the project file manually (and possibly do some other stuff to let the build chain know where things live), but you can run into problems with VS not recognizing things, so unless you're really opposed to installing a preview version of VS it's generally not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specifically install **Visual Studio 2022 preview** to get the **.NET 7.0 SDK** to show up.

**Download:** https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Visual Studio 17.4 (released November 8th, 2022), .NET 7 is included in all GA (non-preview) releases.

**To install the latest version, visit:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/**

Reference:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-4/

> .NET 7 is also releasing today and is part of Visual Studio 2022 17.4

Comment: I thought my VS was up to date, but it's not, it was only at 17.3 (maybe an issue where VS is not automatically updating this version...?) I installed .NET 7 SDK but it doesn't work; you still have to upgrade VS.

Answer (score 5):

Initially, I went from tools->options->preview features, but that didn't seem to stick. But when I went to tools->preview features I checked this box and restarted visual studio it worked. They seem to take you to the same place, so I'm not sure why it didn't stick the first time.

Anyway, checking this box let me build .NET 7 projects in VS2022.

[image: Options window highlighting the "Use preview of the .NET SDK" checkbox]

Comment: Preview is exactly that, preview, bugs are to be expected.